# Center numbered multi-lined headings

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

I'm formatting chapter headings for a book. The chapters are numbered with titles.

A typical heading will look like

[image]

As you can see, the title "Spider Island" isn't quite centered under the number. I achieve this with (2 shift-enters) before the title text. I'm using the font [Black Chancery](http://www.dafont.com/black-chancery.font). I've noticed this discrepancy with pretty much any font, but the amount it is off center changes with the font.

Comment: Just a short comment: Generally it's a bad practice to use multiple consecutive paragraph / line breaks, instead of two shift-enters  it's better to set line spacing.

Comment: @MátéJuhász good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out [following this guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-indent-between-a-list-bullet-or-number-and-text-a2b7b2e4-9c74-4ca7-8fc4-52908f8efb22). The problem is the tab that follows the number, the "space" between where the number and the first character of the heading goes. Removing the tab fixed the issue.

First, right click the number for your heading. Then choose `Adjust List Indents`.

[image]

Then in that dialog, select the following options for zero spacing after the number. Set `Follow number with` to `Nothing`

[image]

The result is:

[image]